# Tidyquant library isn't being recognized in R 4.0.2

Tags: r, r-package, tidyquant

I was trying to learn data analysis by myself to teach my students, so I found on a website the tidyquant library. However, I got stuck in the very beginning. As consequence, I couldn't use the function tq_get(). I leave Here the commands and the message that R studio gave me after I ran the code. I really don't know how to proceed, if someone could help me I would really appreciate it, in addition, I'd be grateful!

I tried to do the following:

```
install.packages ("tidyquant")
library("tidyquant")
```

As a result, I got:

```
>install.packages ("tidyquant")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/luizp/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘timetk’


  There are binary versions available but the
  source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
timetk     2.8.0  2.8.1             FALSE
tidyquant  1.0.3  1.0.4             FALSE

installing the source packages ‘timetk’, ‘tidyquant’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/timetk_2.8.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2960698 bytes (2.8 MB)
downloaded 2.8 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyquant_1.0.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1366418 bytes (1.3 MB)
downloaded 1.3 MB

* installing *source* package 'timetk' ...
** package 'timetk' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called 'ipred'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execução interrompida
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'timetk'
* removing 'C:/Users/luizp/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/timetk'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘timetk’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'timetk' is not available for package 'tidyquant'
* removing 'C:/Users/luizp/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/tidyquant'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyquant’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\luizp\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcrtyPi\downloaded_packages’
> library("tidyquant")
Error in library("tidyquant") : there is no package called ‘tidyquant’
```

Best regards,

Luiz Peres

Comment: try `install.packages("tidyquant", type = "binary")`

Comment: It's missing the package `ipred`. install that one first.

Comment: I tried the Phiver suggestion and it worked! Thank you!